# 301 redirect two domains pointing to the same IP - need to retain google rankings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have two domains example.uk.net and example.co.uk - the example.uk.net has been in use since the website was started but i want to change over to the .co.uk version now - both domains are currently pointing to the same IP/sever - you see the same website on both domains...

Now i know i need to 301 redirect from the .uk.net to the .co.uk but i've read that it is best to do this page by page to retain google rankings/listings and also it is best practise anyway now i just can't seem to get this working as both domains point to the same site i can't use rewrite rules in the htaccess file such as...

```
Redirect 301 /get-a-quote/ http://example.co.uk/get-a-quote/
```

i also seem this piece of code on here that did seem to work but only for the main page, not any sub pages also it still doesn't work on a per page basis only redirecting the whole site...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.co.uk$1 [R=301,L]
```

If anyone could help me out that would be brilliant or if someone has handled something similar in the past - any pointers would be awesome...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a `/`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```